# Reformat categorical data in R

Tags: r, reformat

I have a categorical dataset that I am trying to summarize that has inherent differences in the nature of questions that were asked. The data below represent a questionnaire that had standard close-ended questions, but also questions where one could choose multiple answers from a list. "village" and "income" represent close-ended questions. "responsible.1"...etc... represent a list where the respondent either said yes or no to each.

```
VILLAGE  INCOME         responsible.1   responsible.2   responsible.3   responsible.4   responsible.5
   j     both           DLNR             NA              DEQ              NA           Public
   k     regular.income DLNR             NA              NA               NA           NA
   k     regular.income DLNR             CRM             DEQ              Mayor        NA
   l     both           DLNR             NA              NA               Mayor        NA
   j     both           DLNR             CRM             NA               Mayor        NA
   m     regular.income DLNR             NA              NA               NA           Public
```

What I want is a 3-way table output with "village" and the suite of of "responsible" responsible variables wrapped up into a `ftable`.  This way, I could use the table with numerous R packages for graphs and analyses.

```
        RESPONSIBLE             
VILLAGE INCOME          responsible.1   responsible.2   responsible.3   responsible.4   responsible.5
j       both            2               1               1               1               1
k       regular income  2               1               1               1               0
l       both            1               0               0               1               0
m       regular income  1               0               0               0               1
```

`as.data.frame(table(village, responsible.1)` would get me the first, but I can't figure out how to get the entire thing wrapped up in a nice `ftable`.

Comment: Is the second table showing the desired result?

Comment: Yes, the second table has "RESPONSIBLE" as the variable name with five-level answer. Other two variables are self-explanatory. can you also advise how to paste our "neat" table into the comment board to avoid what just happened?

Comment: You can format the code in your questions by clicking the `{}` icon

Comment: If you want "responsible.1" values to be a third dimension of grouping, then remove it as a column in your desired output and put it in the position above INCOME.

Comment: I think this summarizes what I want.  "responsible.1, etc.." are the levels of the "RESPONSIBLE" variable, associated with their frequencies.  The third dimension would just be "RESPONSIBLE", with those levels and frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

```
> aggregate(dat[-(1:2)], dat[1:2], function(x) sum(!is.na(x)) )
  VILLAGE         INCOME responsible.1 responsible.2 responsible.3 responsible.4 responsible.5
1       j           both             2             1             1             1             1
2       l           both             1             0             0             1             0
3       k regular.income             2             1             1             1             0
4       m regular.income             1             0             0             0             1
```

I'm guessing you actually had another grouping vector , perhaps the first "responsible" column?

I don't really understand the sorting rules but reversing the order of the grouping columns may be closer to what you posted:

```
> aggregate(dat[-(1:2)], dat[2:1], function(x) sum(!is.na(x)) )
          INCOME VILLAGE responsible.1 responsible.2 responsible.3 responsible.4 responsible.5
1           both       j             2             1             1             1             1
2 regular.income       k             2             1             1             1             0
3           both       l             1             0             0             1             0
4 regular.income       m             1             0             0             0             1
```

Comment: This looks great, but how can I turn this into an ftable (i.e., 3-way table, appropriate for categorical graphing and loglm)?  Would love the "responsible.1, etc.." wrapped into a variable "RESPONSIBLE" which is wrapped in 3-way ftable.

Comment: If you would "love" to see a solution to a different data problem then please post an example that provides sufficient complexity to require an amendment.

Comment: And please do not use "etc" as a description of a request. I have developed an intense allergy to that abbreviation in problem statements.

Comment: Apologies, to be clear, what I want is to derive the second table I posted from the first, while having the second table exist as a frequency table.